# Using list.index() to find datetime.date object throws an error

Tags: python, list, datetime, python-datetime

I have a list containing datetime.date() objects. I am trying to find the index of a specific date object.

I tried this -

```
>> index = date_obj.index(datetime.date(2009, 1, 31))
>> *** TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

But when I tried this it worked -

```
>> index = date_obj.index(datetime.strptime("2009-01-31","%Y-%m-%d").date())
>> 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You imported `datetime.datetime` as `datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime
```

`datetime.date` is part of the base library, not `datetime.datetime`

You should just import `datetime` and use `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.date` explicitly or use something like the following to avoid these issues.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

Answer (score 1):

You have probably used

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and the problem is that date is part of the datetime library not from the datetime.datetime module ;)